# How to replace a part of sections in ng-view?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I'm leaning Angular's route. It's very clear how to load a view into ng-view by simply setting **template** attribute.

Let's say I have a widget on a view. When a user navigate to /#/changeWidget, how do I replace ONLY the widget content?

it looks like to me that I can only use single **ng-view**

**main.html**

```
<div ng-app="payment">

    <div ng-view></div>

</div>
```

**js**

```
var app = angular.module("payment",["ngRoute"]);

function listController($scope) {
}

    app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){

        $routeProvider.when('/list', {
            templateUrl: 'templates/list.html',
            controller: listController
        }).
        when('/chagneWidget', {
            templateUrl: 'templates/widget2.html',
            controller: widget2Controller
        }).
        otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/list'
        });

    });
```

So basically, when '/changeWidget' gets triggered, I just want to replace a div from **list.html**

is it possible with router or should I just do...an ajax call and manipulate DOM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not think it is *easily* possible with angular `router` -- and to be honest is quite a big limitation of it. But hey there is this very nice and popular module which offers such possibility: [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router). In case you do not read documentation:

> Warning: UI-Router is pre-beta and under active development. As such, while this library is well-tested, the API is subject to change. Using it in a project that requires guaranteed stability is not recommended.

Is it really necessary to update the widget by changing the route? If not there are plenty of options to do it in angular. If you really have to change the route you can use this hack:

```
$scope.$on("$locationChangeStart", function (event, next, current) {

    if (next == 'your_domanin/your_specific_url') {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $window.history.pushState("object or string", 
            "Title", '/your_specific_url')},20);
        event.preventDefault();
        // ... update your view
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

What would be wrong with using ngSwtich?

> The ngSwitch directive is used to conditionally swap DOM structure on
>   your template based on a scope expression... The directive itself
>   works similar to ngInclude, however, instead of downloading template
>   code (or loading it from the template cache), ngSwitch simply choses
>   one of the nested elements and makes it visible based on which element
>   matches the value obtained from the evaluated expression.

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngSwitch

Comment: Thanks Jon! That's something I missed when I was reading the doc. I wish I could choose two answers. I guess..I should choose artur's since his answer is about route...

Comment: FWIW, the state-based UI router described by artur is under adoption as the standard router for angular, with the original router relegated to an add-on module, so learn your ui-router :)