# Mechanism for change parts of view (angular js)

Tags: angularjs

I am building SPA application and I want to get advice about best practice (organize project structure) for follow issue:

My HOME page have some information and place for authentication or greeting user. In this place I need to show one of two states: first - user not is authorized and I show him form to login, second: - user is authorized and I show him "Hello, man".

I know two bad decision for this. 1. I can use ng-switch (and I think that it's not good). 2. I can use something like ng-include wich will call function for get actual html subview. (I think that it worse then first).

Also I listened about "ui router", but I'am not sure that it best way.

How will better for organize my project and what will better to use?

Comment: Paste your code please !!!

Comment: > Rerer this link
[how-to-replace-a-part-of-sections-in-ng-view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20253162/how-to-replace-a-part-of-sections-in-ng-view)

Comment: @Maher what a code?? Code from my architectural thought? It's stage when I have not code. I think about best way for start.

Comment: @RiazflowerRiaz I think ui-router is not a good solution for the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [ng-switch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch) or [ng-if](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) controlled by a variable `isLogged`

I would make a template login.html and inside I would use ng-switch.

But a more advanced option is to use a directive controlled by events like:

```
.directive('loginDialog', function (AUTH_EVENTS) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    template: '<div ng-if="visible"
                    ng-include="\'login-form.html\'">',
    link: function (scope) {
      var showDialog = function () {
        scope.visible = true;
      };

      scope.visible = false;
      scope.$on(AUTH_EVENTS.notAuthenticated, showDialog);
      scope.$on(AUTH_EVENTS.sessionTimeout, showDialog)
    }
  };
})
```

I use events in that case because this funcionality is extended to the whole application and it's very easy to control the component sending events from any place I need.